# Discord code is running multiple times for no reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I have this piece of code which is running on a discord bot which should repeat what the user says after a command. It does this but repeats it another 7 times after making 8 total runs through that script. Can anyone spot why this might be happening?

Note: The code that actually runs starts from the elif but I put in everything just in case something prior was messing with it.

```
@Client.event 
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content == "s!ping":
    userID = message.author.id
    Client.send_message(message.channel, "<@%s>" % (userID))
  elif message.content.startswith == "s!say":
    args = message.content.split(" ")
    Client.send_message(message.channel, "%s" % (args[1:]))
```

[Image to show test input and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYh2I.png)

Comment: Could you try adding a `if message.author == Client.user: return`?  Also, what version of `discord.py` are you using?

Comment: So im using replit with python 3.6.1 and I just imported the discord library, i do not know how to check its version. I will try your suggestion, thank you for trying to help out

Comment: You can use `import discord; print(discord.__version__)` to see the version.  The reason I ask is because modern distributions of `discord.py` should require you to `await` those `Client.send_message(message.channel, "<@%s>" % (userID))` calls

Comment: The version im using is 0.16.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the CEO of Repl.it. I think this might be a bug with scaling on our service where we might run multiple instances of your server. We'll have a fix for this soon. Meanwhile, I think some other Repl.it users had a fixe for this. Join us on our Discord, there are lots of bot developers there that can help you with this https://discord.gg/xa6S23

Comment: Thank you for the answer I hope the fix will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're sending out a list. 
Try joining the list (which will return a string) after you split it, and send that.
Something like this code below

```
elif message.content.startswith == "s!say":
    args = message.content.split(" ")
    out = " ".join(args[1:]) # concat the message without the "s!say"
    Client.send_message(message.channel, out)
```

Comment: That unfortunately did not work but I do have another observation I made. It will send 5 of the messages first and then after a small delay the last 3 come out. Maybe that will help figure out the problem. Also I did try changing up the code in small ways but I couldnt find a way of it working